# Telerik ExportToExcelML having problems with low years?

Tags: c#, telerik

I'm using ExportToExcelIML to export data from a datagrid to an excel file.

```
ExportToExcelML excelExport = new ExportToExcelML(this.MyGridView);
excelExport.SheetName = "mySheet";
excelExport.ExportHierarchy = true;
excelExport.ExportVisualSettings = true;
excelExport.HiddenColumnOption = HiddenOption.DoNotExport;
excelExport.FileExtension = "xml";
excelExport.RunExport(exportPath);
```

Recently the export failed with the message that a date is erronous. When I looked into the database I saw 0214-08-30 as date in there when I corrected it to 2014-08-30 the export functioned again. So my question here is: Has the export a problem with low years or is it the leading 0 that causes problems there?

Comment: What kind of database are you using? And in the database, what is the format of the datetime?

Comment: datetime in a sql server 2012 db.  like I said the db and c# say the date is ok (tryparse in c#) while the excel export says "no that date is incorrect)

Answer (score 0):

Valid Excel dates are from January 1st, 1900 and on.  Try going into Excel and entering "1899-12-31" and "1900-01-01" into date formatted cells and the latter is the only one that gets auto-formatted.

In your example, the issue is that the year is now 214 and is "too early" for Excel.  Telerik then does not handle the date properly.